# Javascript , how to return false when fill number till 10 decimal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript , how to return false when fill number till 10 decimal ?

This is my code for fill mobile number. I tried to set have to `return false` when user fill number into input `==` 10 decimal but not work , how can i do ?

```html
<p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
<input name="mobile_number" onKeyUp="check_mobile_number_length(this.value)" type="number" class="feedback-input" id="mobile_number" onchange="updateInput_mobile_number(this.value)">
<span id="mySpan_mobile_number" style=" float: left; margin-left: 12px; ^margin-left: 0px; font-size: 12px; color: red;"></span>
</p>

<script>
function check_mobile_number_length(mobile_number_value){
 var mobile_number_value = mobile_number_value.replace(/[^0-9,.]+/g, "");
 document.getElementById("mobile_number").value = mobile_number_value;
 var mobile_number_value = document.getElementById("mobile_number").value;
 
 if(mobile_number_value.length==10) 
 {
  document.getElementById("mobile_number").style.border = "1px solid rgba(72,72,72,0.4)";
  document.getElementById("mySpan_mobile_number").innerHTML = "";
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("mobile_number").style.border = "1px solid red";
  document.getElementById("mySpan_mobile_number").innerHTML = "please enter mobile number for 10 decimal";
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What effect do you think returning `false` should have? By that point your function has already modified the value in the field.

Comment: when fill number == 10 decimal. user can not fill number into input

Comment: So is your goal to return `false`, which is how your question is phrased, or is your goal to prevent the user entering more than 10 digits?

Comment: return false like this https://jsfiddle.net/eeqthmtw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time the user's key has been released, the character has already been typed. Hence, you can't use `onkeyup` for this. Here, I have used `onkeypress`, which fires when a key has been pressed.

Also, while `return false` works when directly inline, here it would be better to directly refuse the event, by passing the event to the function, and then calling `.preventDefault()` on it. This prevents the default action after the event (i.e. for `onkeypress` prevents the key being pressed, for `onclick` prevents the click, etc).

Here, I have created a basic example of how this can be done. Hopefully you can adapt it to meet your needs:

```js
function check_mobile_value(ele, ev) {
  if (ele.value.length>=10) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeypress="check_mobile_value(this, event)">
```